Siri volume is 0 when in driving focus in car, but works when earbuds in
For some reason, when driving focus is enabled, and Siri is connected to my car’s Bluetooth, Siri is not audible. For the longest time I thought that driving focus was busted entirely because the screen would light up, the Siri animation would flash for a while, but would not do anything. I eventually figured out that it was responding, asking for a follow up yes or no or the like, but since I wasn’t giving it a confirmation, it would just time out. Volume on maps, Waze, music is fine, just Siri. Pressing volume up on either the car or the iPhone does nothing while Siri is speaking.
If I put in earbuds, then I can now hear Siri talk, and everything seems to work… But how do I get the volume on Siri to work with my car’s Bluetooth? It is a 10-year-old Toyota, no CarPlay, fairly dumb audio on the car (‘press talk button and say yes to confirm”)

It ought to remember each volume control separately. On mine I can use the buttons on the steering wheel for this. It changes the volume of whatever is currently playing, whether it is Siri, a phone call or music etc. Try adjusting the level right at the time she should actually be speaking.

@Tetsujin yup, you’d think that, but no. I tried the steering wheel volume, the radio volume, and the phone buttons.
